# CXX0017: Error symbol "node" not found

Tags: c

```
void parse_adts_bitstream(AAC_HEAP *heap, BIT_BUFFER *buff )
    {
        ADTS_FRAME *curFrame = malloc(sizeof(ADTS_FRAME));
        ADTS_HEADER *header  = &(curFrame->header);


        /* Update ADTS First frame pointer */
        if( curFrame != NULL )
        {    
            heap->adts = curFrame;
            memset( curFrame, 0, sizeof(ADTS_FRAME));
        }   
        else
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "\nError : malloc failure.. ");
            exit(0);
        }



        /* Parse all frame and get bitstream information */
        while ( buff->nBytesRead < buff->bufferSize )
        {


            /* Get ADTS Header Information */
            header->fix.syncword                           = (short)getbits(12, buff);
            header->fix.id                                 = (char )getbits( 1, buff);
            header->fix.layer                              = (char )getbits( 2, buff);
            header->fix.protection_absent                  = (char )getbits( 1, buff);
            header->fix.profile_ObjectType                 = (char )getbits( 2, buff);
            header->fix.sampling_frequency_index           = (char )getbits( 4, buff);
            header->fix.private_bit                        = (char )getbits( 1, buff);
            header->fix.channel_configuration              = (char )getbits( 3, buff);
            header->fix.original_copy                      = (char )getbits( 1, buff);
            header->fix.home                               = (char )getbits( 1, buff);
            header->var.copyright_identification_bit       = (char )getbits( 1, buff);
            header->var.copyright_identification_start     = (char )getbits( 1, buff);
            header->var.aac_frame_length                   = (short)getbits(13, buff);
            header->var.adts_buffer_fullness               = (short)getbits(11, buff);
            header->var.number_of_raw_data_blocks_in_frame = (char )getbits( 2, buff);

            /* Get frame data */
            curFrame->data  = getdata( header->var.aac_frame_length - ADTS_FRAME_LENGTH, buff );
            curFrame->data -= ADTS_FRAME_LENGTH;

            /* Parse raw data block */
            if ( header->var.number_of_raw_data_blocks_in_frame >= 0 )
            {

                heap->rdb = curFrame->data;
                parse_raw_data_block(heap,buff);
            }

            /* Allocate Memory for next Frame */
            curFrame->next = NULL;
            if ( buff->nBytesRead < buff->bufferSize )
            {
                curFrame->next = malloc(sizeof(ADTS_FRAME));
                if(curFrame->next != NULL)
                    curFrame = (ADTS_FRAME*)curFrame->next;
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stdout, "\nError : malloc failure.. ");
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
        }



        return;   
    }
```

CXX0017: Error symbol "node" not found , in "watch 1",
i am facing this error when i debug my project.
I did not use "node" variable anywhere in my programm.
Why this error come.
"parse_raw_data_block(heap,buff)" -when i called this function this error come ,if i     commented this function error wont come.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CXX0017: Error symbol "node" not found , in "watch 1"

sounds very much like it's a variable being watched in the *debugger* (and, in fact, it *is* [such a beast](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3c87a746-e2f6-44ee-a506-65fd412e5a69/debug-watch-error-cxx0017-symbol-not-found-beginner?forum=vsdebug)), which may or may not be a variable in your code.

Even if it *was* in your code, it may be at a different stack level to the one you're currently on.

It's likely that a watchpoint has been set on a variable called `node`. You just need to remove that watchpoint, the method used would be dictated by the debugger itself.

For example, In Visual Studio Debugger, I believe you can go to the watch window and right-click on an expression to delete it.

Comment: CXX0017: Error symbol "node" not found, Error is only this,i did not use any variable like node when i debug it show me "Unhandled exception at 0x002f2ea7 in bs_info.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0cbbb6b4" and break,then i watch and showed me the error

Comment: No one is here to help me